# Check if Field is from specific class

Tags: java, reflection

To display keys & values of a dataobject, I'm using a Collection of AccessibleObjects to generate a table. The AccessibleObject'S are collected on a specific time, but the values are read, when the render have to render the table.

The Problem: I'm not only want to hold AccessibleObject's of one specific Class. Is it possible to check a AccessibleObject Class-Origin? e.g. `accessibleObject.fromClass(classType);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean

```
Member member = field or method;
Class clazz = member.getDeclaringClass()
```

to get the class the field appears in.

Note: this is the actual class, not the class you might have used to look it up. e.g. say A has a field `x` and a subclass B.  If you get field x of class B, it will say the declaring class is A.  This is because A and B can have a field called `x`.

Comment: I've done an mistake. To extend my system, I'm extended the collection to hold `AccessibleObject` instead of `Field`, because of the possiblilty to render `Method` values as well as `Field`'s. Is there a possibility to get the DeclaringClass?

Comment: If you can change this to Member or cast it to Member, you can still get this.  Method and Field are `Member`

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll mark your answer in a few minutes as correct. Have a nice day.

Comment: +1 yes we can do this as all the subclasses of AccessibleObject implement Member. Nice catch.

Comment: But if there is some other subclass of AccessibleObject in future and if it does not implement Member then it may be a problem. But not in foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class c = field.getDeclaringClass();
```

From JavaDoc:

> Returns the Class object representing the class or interface
>   that declares the field represented by this Field object.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm looking for an Method to check the CLass of AccessibleObject (Superclass of Field).